# Quotes Proving Problematic within String in Angular Code

Tags: javascript, angular

I have some code in my Angular view component that's giving me problems because of quotes. I am using `\` to handle the quotes within the string, but I'm still getting a syntax error.

This is what the code looks like:

```
<button *ngIf="selectedAction?.division?.col !== 'send \"ready to serve\" email'" md-menu-item>
    <span class="md-menu-text">Send "Ready to Serve" Email</span>
</button>
```

Does this look correct? Is there something else I need to do to handle the quotes in this string?

Comment: Try using &quot. `'send &quotready to serve&quot email'"`

Comment: Use like this : *ngIf='selectedAction?.division?.col !== "send \"ready to serve\" email"'

Comment: Interesting. That gets rid of the syntax error. But the my `!==` logic doesn't work as a result. In other words, it doesn't recognize 'send &quotready to serve&quot email' as `===` or `==` to 'send "ready to serve" email".

Comment: Same problem with the second suggestion. It gets rid of the syntax error, but then the conditional check doesn't work as expected. And that's the case even if I use `!=` instead of `!==`. Ideas?

Comment: Check this Stackblitz its working perfect : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9e3wbz

Comment: My code is such that, if the current `selectedAction?.division?.col` is NOT equal to the string passed in, then it should display. However, if the string value IS equal to the current `selectedAction?.division?.col` value, then it should not display as an option. This same logic works for all my other options (and they don't use quotes). But with this particular one it's not working -- because it's showing up as an option even when the two are equal. So the conditional check just on this one string value is failing. All I can conclude is that it doesn't see these string values as identical.